# Como validar el valor varios TextField?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Tengo un formulario .FXML con muchos TextField y un boton para hacer click y realiza una operación matematica con cada uno de los valores ingresados en TextField.

Creé un metodo que obtiene el valor de los campos de texto y realiza la operación matematica.

Pero si alguno de los campos de texto se ha cambiado el valor, se debe volver a recalcular haciendo click en el boton.

Yo necesito que al oprimir la tecla enter en cualquier TextField, automaticamente se ejecute el metodo de la operación matematica, pero no quiero usar el metodo keyPressed en cada campo de texto, sería un codigo largo, invocar el metodo keyPressed para cada TextField.

Estaba pensando en crear un oyente o una especie de Binding,  que unaque detecte cuando hubo cambios en los campos de texto, o cuando el valor digitado sea mayor a cero.

```
txt1..textProperty().addListener...
txt2..textProperty().addListener...
txt3..textProperty().addListener...
txt4..textProperty().addListener...
txt5..textProperty().addListener...
...
...
```

ése metodo funciona, pero tengo muchos TextField, y tengo que repetir muchas veces ése codigo. Y no quiero hacer eso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he aquí el formulario...

Comment: Para qué describir el formulario si lo puedes mostrar (ojalá como texto en tu pregunta)?

Comment: @Alfabravo listo, ya inserté la imagen

Comment: Puedes hacer 2 cosas al menos. Una es crear una clase que extienda o implemente del listener de interes y obligues a todos los componentes que usen ese listener. La otra seria crear en el controlador un listener para un solo campo de texto....y los demas campo utilicen el mismo listener.....lo que te quedaria es usar un switcher para identificar quien genero el evento

Comment: Podrías crear una lista de TextField en lugar de tener muchas variables, con lo que con un bucle podrías asignar a todos el mismo listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes declarar un solo listener y aplicarlos a todos los TextField de interés.

Ejm:

```
EventHandler<KeyEvent> teclaPresionada = (event) -> {
// Colocar todo el codigo aca
};

campo1.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, teclaPresionada);
campo2.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, teclaPresionada);
campo3.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, teclaPresionada);
campo4.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, teclaPresionada);  
campo5.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, teclaPresionada);
```